# TFS not fully connected

Tags: tfs

We are working in a ERP project with `ASP .Net 4.5`. `VS2012,` `MSSQL2008 R2`.

TFS is installed in main server.  Before yesterday, everything was fine. we all were connected through TFS and every project in the Solution was connected.

For a sudden network restructure, we all got problem with the connection with TFS. some of the projects are connected through the tfs. but most of the projects are not connected with tfs.

Now we restored the previous network connection. but still there is the same problem. some of the projects are connected and some are not. what could be the solution?

Comment: What do you mean "not connected"? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Is Visual Studio "Working offline", you can check in File, Source Control... ?

Comment: It might be that your solutions are still in `offline mode` after your network interruption, go to `File > Source Control > Go Online`

Comment: thanks all for you effort. I have solved it in a way. Finally we are working again as we were working before. What I did, I will post it as an answer immediately